# Which automated theorem provers can address the combinatorics of periods in strings?

Tags: computer-science, combinatorics-on-words

Five years ago, I made a [conjecture](http://list.seqfan.eu/pipermail/seqfan/2009-January/000524.html) on the number of correlation classes that are exhibited by pairs of words in an alphabet of a given size. I later [speculated](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~leopardi/ACCMCC2010-Leopardi-words-strings-talk.pdf) that the conjecture could be tackled via automated theorem proving. I would now like to make some progress on this conjecture, by finding out whether there are any automated theorem provers capable of at least formulating a simpler statement along the same lines.

The simpler statement that I have chosen is Theorem 1 of Halava, V., Harju, T., & Ilie, L. (2000). [*Periods and binary words*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jcta.1999.3014). Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A, 89(2), 298-303. This theorem is a restatement of part of Theorem 5.1 of Guibas, L. J., & Odlyzko, A. M. (1981). Periods in strings. Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A, 30(1), 19-42:

> Theorem 1: For any alphabet $A$ and any word $w \in A^*$, there exists
>   a word $w' \in \{0,1\}^*$ such that $\mathcal{P}(w') = \mathcal{P}(w).$

Here $\mathcal{P}(w)$ is the set of *periods* of the word $w$:

> An integer $p,$ with $1 \leqslant p \leqslant |w|,$ is called a
>   *period* of $w$ if $w_i = w_{i+p},$ for all $1 \leqslant i \leqslant |w|-p.$

My questions are:

1. Which automated theorem provers are capable of formulating Theorem 1 with its proper semantics (i.e arbitrary finite strings over an arbitrary finite alphabet)?
2. Which automated theorem provers are cable of *proving* Theorem 1, along the lines of Guibas and Odlyzko, or Halava, Harju and Ilie, or in an otherwise intelligible manner?
3. How much work would be involved in creating such a formulation and proof? Would this be an undergraduate student assignment, a PhD project, or a decades-long project for a research team? Or would it require the development of new types of theorem provers?

Comment: What does $\mathcal{P}(w') \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}(w)$ mean?

Comment: It would be helpful if you outlined the sort of proof you want automated, or at least tell us what techniques it uses.

Comment: How automated would you expect things to be. I could imagine that most common proof assistantants should be able to formulate and proove this thing, with the help of an experienced user and taking the paper you referenced as a guideline. In the end you will obtain a formal proof which can be verified automatically. If you want the proof *generation* to be automatic, and follow the direction of that paper, that would likely be a completely different thing.

Comment: Is it just me, or is this Theorem rather trivial? You compute the length $n=\lvert w\rvert$ and period $p=\mathcal P(w)$ of $w$, then take a single one followed by $p-1$ zeros, and repeat that until the length of the word $w'$ formed in this way equals $n$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MvG: consider the word $w=001200$, with $\mathcal{P}(w)=\{4,5\}$.  Note that for finite strings, the gcd of two periods need not be a period.

Comment: @NeilStrickland: Thanks for the clarification; I missed the fact that $\mathcal P$ is a *set*. Even though the question does state it. Now the question makes a lot more sense to me.

Comment: @MvG, Neil Strickland: In this question, as per Halava, Harju and Ilie, indices are counted from 1, and $|w|$ is always a period, so $w = 001200$ has $\mathcal{P}(w)=\{4,5,6\}.$ As for the gcd of two periods, see Lemma 1 of Halava, Harju and Ilie. Guibas and Odlyzko use indices from 0 to $|w|-1$ and then 0 is always a period of $w.$ I am sticking to the notation of Halava, Harju and Ilie in this question so as not to confuse the issue.

Comment: @MvG: I am looking for an automated proof, because I want to be able to use the techniques learnt in finding the automated proof to inform what I might be able to do with my conjecture. I have tried quite a few times to manually enumerate all of the cases of overlaps between two strings that are involved in my conjecture, and I have always felt that doing so was too prone to error.

Comment: @MvG, and yes, by *automated proof*, I would like the theorem prover to automatically generate something intelligible in a reasonable time. Given the state of the art, I am not sure if this is too much to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that

- Any of the standard theorem provers could formulate your statement without much trouble.  There would be various choices about what kind of data structures to use (implicitly or explicitly), and the right choice might make a big difference to the ease of writing proofs.
- I had a quick look at the paper of Halava et al, which is five pages long and is written explicitly as an algorithm to find $w'$.  I think that anyone who was reasonably fluent with a proof assistant could encode and verify that proof without much trouble.  One would expect the formalised proof to be several times longer than the paper.  For this kind of work, I don't think there is much reason to prefer any one of the standard systems over the others.
- I do not think that any existing proof assistant has any chance of finding such a proof for itself, unless you can cast the problem into a form that can be attacked by a SAT solver.  I don't really know anything about SAT solvers myself but [this post](http://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/recent-news-concerning-the-erdos-discrepancy-problem/) by Gowers seems relevant and interesting.
- If you need to enumerate a bunch of cases to consider, I would be more inclined to use a system like Maple or Mathematica (or a general programming language) to do the initial enumeration.  Later on, you could feed the results into a proof assistant to validate the overall logic if necessary.